# Safari + voiceover not reading labels with nested elements correctly

Tags: html, safari, wai-aria, voiceover

I've stumbled upon an issue (i think) with how voiceover + safari interact with reading labels which have nested elements within them.

Here's a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hidden-moon-p7kop2) with the issue. If you use voiceover + chrome, it will properly read the label "text here" in its entirety. However, if you do the same in safari, it will read "text and 1 more item".

Is this a bug with safari/voiceover? Or is there something that can be done to avoid this (without just sticking an aria-label onto it)?

Answer (score 0):

Voiceover on Safari on **iOS** works just fine.  I'm guessing you're on a Mac?  I hear "text here" for the checkbox label. See the red highlighted box in the image.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

The word "here" is also "tab stop", so to speak, for Voiceover after navigating from "text here" because that's how Voiceover handles labels that have embedded `<div>` elements.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

I'm not sure why Safari says "and 1 more item" but I'm almost certain it's because of the nested `<div>`.  You can probably work around the issue by using the **undocumented** and **not officially supported** `text` role.  Change your codesandbox to:

```
<div role="text">
  text <div>here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would `role="presentation"` be the right thing for that inner `<div>`? (i.e. ignore the div, just read the text inside it)

Comment: No, that's not what `role="presentation"` means.  A `<div>` is already a non-semantic element without a role.  It essentially is already a "presentation" role.  See https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/#el-div.  Did you try the `text` role?